# Understanding this behaviour (r-value reference)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm doing some tests with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string& changeSomething(string&& s) {
    s[0] = 'a';
    return s;
}

int main() {
    string s = changeSomething("hello");
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Here I pass a rvalue reference to the function, and return a reference to the object. The problem here is that I thought this would give UB, due the fact that I'm passing a r-value to the function and it doesn't have a memory address assigned, but this outputs:

> aello

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Just because it *appears* to work, doesn't mean it's not UB.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I mean, you're right. But as I can't check wheter is UB or not, I would like someone to point out if it really is or not.

Comment: You can use `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined` to get a basic idea. Then use the one true debugger - printf to see when the constructor/destructors are called.

Comment: This code is actually well defined  (1)  A temporary `std::string` is created that is initialised with the string literal `"hello"`.  (2)  A reference to that temporary is passed to `changeSomething()`.   (3)   `changeSomething()` changes the temporary, and returns a reference to it.  (4)   Control returns to `main()`, and the returned reference (which refers to the temporary) is used to initialise `s`  - which happens by copying the (modified) temporary  (5)   The temporary ceases to exist st the end of the expression/statement.    (6)   In the next statement `s` is output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not UB. The temporary object is not destructed until the end of the expression, and you copy it within the same expression. To get a basic first idea, you can use `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`. It's not perfect, but helps. And to get a more precise idea of when constructor/destructors are called, you can print something from them:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Noisy {
  char const* data;
  Noisy(char const* ch) : data{ch} { std::puts("Noisy()"); }
  Noisy(Noisy const& oth) : data{oth.data} { std::puts("Noisy(Noisy const&)"); }
  ~Noisy() { std::puts("~Noisy()"); }
};

Noisy& changeSomething(Noisy&& s) { return s; }

int main() {
  Noisy s = changeSomething("Hello");
  std::puts(s.data);
}
```

The output is:

```
Noisy()
Noisy(Noisy const&)
~Noisy()
Hello
~Noisy()
```

You can see that copying is done before destruction, so nothing is accessed after being destructed. See it on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sT3bhv).

Comment: Where is `Noisy()` called?

Comment: @Norhther when you pass `"Hello"` to `changeSomething`, a temporary object of type `Noisy` is created. This is where the constructor is called.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!